# How does [branch] get executed in HLSL?

Tags: multithreading, if-statement, gpu, directx, hlsl

The [`[branch]` attribute can mark an `if` statement in HLSL to make it execute only one branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-if) instead of all branches and discarding the results like when using `[flatten]`.

My question is how can this actually work, when a branch diverges withing a warp/wavefront? As far as I know, in this case all threads must execute all branches taken by any of the threads in the warp (like when using `[flatten]`) which is consequence of the fact, that they are all within the same SIMD block and must execute the same instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since GeForce series 6xx GPUs do actually support branching, though in limited form and with performance cost. The `[branch]` and `[flatten]` tags are just hints to the compiler to prefer one or the other **if supported and possible**. It basically depends on hardware and on the driver, so different hardware or different driver versions might in the end determine a different execution from what you specified with the tag.

You can find more info online, for example [check this link](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems2/part-iv-general-purpose-computation-gpus-primer/chapter-34-gpu-flow-control-idioms)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I didn't know about MIMD and similar. It also seems a bit strange to me that people still say that branching in shaders is deadly, though it seems that it is supported on 8 year old hardware.

Comment: It's supported but with limits (only on some kind of shaders -  only on some hardware - only on some driver versions) and with performance costs. So it's still better to avoid it if possible. Consider that if the branch is not too complex, usually the compiler does a pretty good job of flattening the branches. Still, there are occasions where branching might be preferable (especially on compute shaders).

Comment: What about, let’s say, a ray tracer in a compute shader? It usually involves a lot of branching with quite complex branches.